# Error tyring to get to storage admin page

Tags: magento2.3.2

Appologies as I am not much of a dev, more unix admin... So please be patient and help :)

I get an error when I try to get to the Magento 2.3.2 storage admin area via:

Store->Configuration->Advanced->System:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Flag->getFlagData() called at [vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Block/System/Config/System/Storage/Media/Synchronize.php:115]
#2 Magento\MediaStorage\Block\System\Config\System\Storage\Media\Synchronize->getSyncStorageParams() called at [generated/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Block/System/Config/System/Storage/Media/Synchronize/Interceptor.php:76]
#3 Magento\MediaStorage\Block\System\Config\System\Storage\Media\Synchronize\Interceptor->getSyncStorageParams() called at [vendor/magento/module-media-storage/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/system/storage/media/synchronize.phtml:37]
#4 include('/var/www/html/ve...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:59]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\MediaStorage\Block\System\Config\System\Storage\Media\Synchronize\Interceptor#000000003bfc5ad7000000001c07e6a1#, '/var/www/html/ve...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:271]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/html/ve...') called at [generated/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Block/System/Config/System/Storage/Media/Synchronize/Interceptor.php:219]
#7 Magento\MediaStorage\Block\System\Config\System\Storage\Media\Synchronize\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/html/ve...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:301]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php:129]
#9 Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Block/System/Config/System/Storage/Media/Synchronize.php:59]
```

Comment: may issue generate because of third party modules, so need to disable one by one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I patched as follows to unserialize a serialized string:

> File: /vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php

**Find:**

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**replace by:**

```
public function unserialize($string)
{
    $result = json_decode($string, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        /* please add this condition */
        if(false !== @unserialize($string)){
            return unserialize($string);
        }
        /* please add this condition */
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unable to unserialize value.');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you also for taking the time to comment, but again unfortunately this did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands

```
redis-cli 
flushall
exit
```

It works for me

Comment: Thank you for taking time to make a suggestion, but, I do not have redis installed, should I have? This was an upgrade all the way from 2.1 pretty much one step at a time and upgrading PHP when neccassary.